# Does Spring Cloud Contract DSL support bodyFileName

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, wiremock, spring-cloud-contract

I am trying to define a contract using spring-cloud-contract framework that for a specific request returns a response with big body. This body is always the same. So I would prefer to store this body in some static file. And generated Wiremock mapping would use `bodyFileName` to refer to that static file with response body content.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't. But the DSL uses Groovy so you could theoretically download the body from somewhere. From the jar with stubs for example

Comment: Thanks, @marcin-grzejszczak! Yes this is that am going to use right now. I just wondered if it is officially supported by spring cloud contract.
But suggested approach would create in our case a big mapping file. As that static content that we want to return in response by stub might be few hundreds lines.

Comment: Currently we don't support any other way of doing this. The problem is that we're automatically building stubs for you so we would need to know which files should we copy to the output jar. Actually you can file an issue in Spring Cloud Contract and we can continue the discussion there cause the topic seems really interesting